# how to write block by block database records into a file in python

Tags: python, impala, file-writing

I am extracting `database records` from a table and I want to `write` those into a `file`. The scenario that I have is that my table has billions of rows in it. So I cannot load all the records in one go an write them as I run out of memory. So I was doing write into the file one record at a time. My current code is:

```
from impala.dbapi import connect

connection = connect()
cur = connection.cursor()
sql = "<SQL Statement>"
cur.execute(sql)
write_file = open("file1.csv",'w')
write_file.write("<column header>")

row = cur.fetchone()
while row is not None:
      write_file.write("\n" + str(row)[1:-1])
      row = cur.fetchone()

write_file.close()
```

By doing this it takes a lot of time because of sequential processing of that many records one at a time. What I want to try is to write a block of records at a time (say `1 million` records at a time). How can I write a `block of record` at a time instead of one record at a time?

**NOTE:** The database that I am using is `impala`

**UPDATE:** **This is the profiling result from the execution of the above code**

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)

   148032    0.162    0.000    0.563    0.000 TBinaryProtocol.py:109(writeI32)
    49344    0.077    0.000    0.261    0.000 TBinaryProtocol.py:121(writeString)
    49344    0.256    0.000  146.854    0.003 TBinaryProtocol.py:125(readMessageBegin)
    49344    0.011    0.000    0.011    0.000 TBinaryProtocol.py:145(readMessageEnd)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TBinaryProtocol.py:20(<module>)
   148032    0.257    0.000  146.350    0.001 TBinaryProtocol.py:205(readI32)
    49344    0.084    0.000    0.549    0.000 TBinaryProtocol.py:220(readString)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TBinaryProtocol.py:226(TBinaryProtocolFactory)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TBinaryProtocol.py:236(TBinaryProtocolAccelerated)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TBinaryProtocol.py:24(TBinaryProtocol)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TBinaryProtocol.py:258(TBinaryProtocolAcceleratedFactory)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TBinaryProtocol.py:39(__init__)
    49344    0.134    0.000    0.828    0.000 TBinaryProtocol.py:44(writeMessageBegin)
    49344    0.010    0.000    0.010    0.000 TBinaryProtocol.py:54(writeMessageEnd)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TCLIService.py:2364(GetOperationStatus_args)
      155    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TCLIService.py:2375(__init__)
      155    0.001    0.000    0.002    0.000 TCLIService.py:2398(write)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TCLIService.py:2425(GetOperationStatus_result)
      155    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TCLIService.py:2435(__init__)
      155    0.001    0.000    0.002    0.000 TCLIService.py:2438(read)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TCLIService.py:2485(CancelOperation_args)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TCLIService.py:2546(CancelOperation_result)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.112    2.112 TCLIService.py:259(ExecuteStatement)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.112    2.112 TCLIService.py:275(recv_ExecuteStatement)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TCLIService.py:2761(write)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TCLIService.py:2788(GetResultSetMetadata_result)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TCLIService.py:2798(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TCLIService.py:2801(read)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TCLIService.py:2848(FetchResults_args)
    49186    0.030    0.000    0.030    0.000 TCLIService.py:2859(__init__)
    49186    0.171    0.000    0.418    0.000 TCLIService.py:2882(write)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TCLIService.py:2909(FetchResults_result)
    49186    0.047    0.000    0.047    0.000 TCLIService.py:2919(__init__)
    49186    0.195    0.000   93.752    0.002 TCLIService.py:2922(read)
      155    0.001    0.000    0.114    0.001 TCLIService.py:499(GetOperationStatus)
      155    0.001    0.000    0.012    0.000 TCLIService.py:507(send_GetOperationStatus)
      155    0.001    0.000    0.101    0.001 TCLIService.py:515(recv_GetOperationStatus)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.002 TCLIService.py:589(GetResultSetMetadata)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TCLIService.py:597(send_GetResultSetMetadata)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.002 TCLIService.py:605(recv_GetResultSetMetadata)
    49186    0.145    0.000  241.626    0.005 TCLIService.py:619(FetchResults)
    49186    0.276    0.000    2.709    0.000 TCLIService.py:627(send_FetchResults)
    49186    0.318    0.000  238.771    0.005 TCLIService.py:635(recv_FetchResults)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TCLIService.py:770(Processor)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 TCLIService.py:9(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TProtocol.py:20(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TProtocol.py:23(TProtocolException)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TProtocol.py:39(TProtocolBase)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TProtocol.py:419(TProtocolFactory)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TProtocol.py:42(__init__)
  2245378    4.023    0.000  190.070    0.000 TSocket.py:103(read)
    49344    0.153    0.000    0.925    0.000 TSocket.py:123(write)
    49344    0.012    0.000    0.012    0.000 TSocket.py:137(flush)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TSocket.py:141(TServerSocket)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 TSocket.py:20(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TSocket.py:28(TSocketBase)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TSocket.py:29(_resolveAddr)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TSocket.py:47(TSocket)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TSocket.py:50(__init__)
    49344    0.022    0.000    0.022    0.000 TSocket.py:69(isOpen)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TSocket.py:72(setTimeout)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TSocket.py:81(open)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TTransport.py:103(TServerTransportBase)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TTransport.py:116(TTransportFactoryBase)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TTransport.py:123(TBufferedTransportFactory)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TTransport.py:131(TBufferedTransport)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TTransport.py:139(__init__)
    49344    0.057    0.000    0.079    0.000 TTransport.py:145(isOpen)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 TTransport.py:148(open)
   197376    0.473    0.000  145.718    0.001 TTransport.py:154(read)
   246720    0.177    0.000    0.376    0.000 TTransport.py:162(write)
    49344    0.177    0.000    1.156    0.000 TTransport.py:165(flush)
    49344    0.015    0.000    0.015    0.000 TTransport.py:173(cstringio_buf)
  2196034    8.376    0.000   57.806    0.000 TTransport.py:177(cstringio_refill)
   197376    0.389    0.000  146.149    0.001 TTransport.py:54(readAll)
       46    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 abc.py:89(<genexpr>)
       34    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 collections.py:329(<genexpr>)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 collections.py:353(<genexpr>)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 collections.py:355(<genexpr>)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 collections.py:38(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 collections.py:387(Counter)
       44    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 collections.py:54(__setitem__)
       28    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 collections.py:73(__iter__)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 decimal.py:3782(__init__)
       27    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 decimal.py:3809(<genexpr>)
       27    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 decimal.py:3816(<genexpr>)
    49186    0.018    0.000    0.018    0.000 hiveserver2.py:113(buffersize)
    49344    3.269    0.000 1590.514    0.032 hiveserver2.py:116(wrapper)
100680255   29.571    0.000   29.571    0.000 hiveserver2.py:122(has_result_set)
        1    0.000    0.000   39.283   39.283 hiveserver2.py:140(execute)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.112    2.112 hiveserver2.py:142(op)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hiveserver2.py:146(_get_socket)
        2    0.004    0.002    0.029    0.014 hiveserver2.py:15(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000   39.283   39.283 hiveserver2.py:154(_execute_sync)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hiveserver2.py:158(_get_transport)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hiveserver2.py:166(_reset_state)
        1    0.002    0.002   37.169   37.169 hiveserver2.py:175(_wait_to_finish)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hiveserver2.py:187(connect_to_impala)
      154    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hiveserver2.py:189(_get_sleep_interval)
 50340127   50.937    0.000 1760.004    0.000 hiveserver2.py:207(fetchone)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 hiveserver2.py:209(open_session)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.112    2.112 hiveserver2.py:226(execute_statement)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.002 hiveserver2.py:237(get_result_schema)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hiveserver2.py:24(HiveServer2Connection)
 50340127   52.496    0.000 1693.039    0.000 hiveserver2.py:250(next)
    49186 1153.582    0.023 1584.908    0.032 hiveserver2.py:263(fetch_results)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hiveserver2.py:30(__init__)
      155    0.002    0.000    0.115    0.001 hiveserver2.py:406(get_operation_status)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 hiveserver2.py:49(cursor)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hiveserver2.py:66(HiveServer2Cursor)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hiveserver2.py:71(__init__)
    49344    0.039    0.000    0.039    0.000 hiveserver2.py:76(err_if_rpc_not_ok)
    49186    0.017    0.000    0.017    0.000 hiveserver2.py:89(description)
      391    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:130(__getitem__)
       42    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:134(__setitem__)
      145    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:138(append)
   135/54    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:140(getwidth)
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:178(__init__)
     1116    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 sre_parse.py:182(__next)
      308    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:195(match)
      983    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.000 sre_parse.py:201(get)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:205(tell)
      114    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:210(isident)
       21    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:216(isname)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:225(_class_escape)
       32    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:257(_escape)
    47/12    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.000 sre_parse.py:301(_parse_sub)
    52/13    0.001    0.000    0.004    0.000 sre_parse.py:379(_parse)
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:67(__init__)
       12    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.000 sre_parse.py:675(parse)
       29    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:72(opengroup)
       29    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:83(closegroup)
       98    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:90(__init__)
   442674    0.315    0.000    0.315    0.000 ttypes.py:2296(__init__)
   590232    0.262    0.000    0.262    0.000 ttypes.py:2380(__init__)
  1032906    2.061    0.000    2.061    0.000 ttypes.py:2644(__init__)
    49186    0.033    0.000    0.033    0.000 ttypes.py:2786(__init__)
    49344    0.050    0.000    0.050    0.000 ttypes.py:2896(__init__)
      155    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ttypes.py:5195(__init__)
      155    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ttypes.py:5266(__init__)
       21    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ttypes.py:540(__init__)
    49186    0.055    0.000    0.055    0.000 ttypes.py:5764(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ttypes.py:5840(TFetchResultsResp)
    49186    0.044    0.000    0.044    0.000 ttypes.py:5855(__init__)
        1  286.275  286.275 2121.074 2121.074 test.py:24(func1)
        1    0.001    0.001 2121.112 2121.112 test.py:3(<module>)
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_sre.compile}
       35    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_sre.getlower}
   148032    0.134    0.000    0.134    0.000 {_struct.pack}
   148032    0.107    0.000    0.107    0.000 {_struct.unpack}
  2294724    4.074    0.000    4.074    0.000 {cStringIO.StringIO}
      251    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {getattr}
    99230    0.061    0.000    0.061    0.000 {isinstance}
    24/13    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {issubclass}
55672069/55672017    7.519    0.000    7.519    0.000 {len}
    49351    0.061    0.000    0.061    0.000 {max}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method '__contains__' of 'frozenset' objects}
       11    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method '__subclasses__' of 'type' objects}
1107483909  105.411    0.000  105.411    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        4    0.220    0.055    0.220    0.055 {method 'close' of 'file' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'connect' of '_socket.socket' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'endswith' of 'str' objects}
    49198    0.249    0.000    0.249    0.000 {method 'extend' of 'list' objects}
    49344    0.021    0.000    0.021    0.000 {method 'getvalue' of 'cStringIO.StringO' objects}
 50340126   32.139    0.000   32.139    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'list' objects}
   246720    0.140    0.000    0.140    0.000 {method 'read' of 'cStringIO.StringI' objects}
       23    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'readline' of 'file' objects}
  2245378  185.259    0.000  185.259    0.000 {method 'recv' of '_socket.socket' objects}
    49344    0.764    0.000    0.764    0.000 {method 'send' of '_socket.socket' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'setter' of 'property' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'settimeout' of '_socket.socket' objects}
       45    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
       11    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'startswith' of 'str' objects}
       45    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'strip' of 'str' objects}
   246720    0.198    0.000    0.198    0.000 {method 'write' of 'cStringIO.StringO' objects}
 50340130   34.491    0.000   34.491    0.000 {method 'write' of 'file' objects}
      193    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {min}
        4    0.800    0.200    0.800    0.200 {open}
1057142741   84.179    0.000   84.179    0.000 {ord}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.getcwd}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.lstat}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.urandom}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {repr}
      146    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {setattr}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {sys._getframe}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {thread.allocate_lock}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {thread.get_ident}
    49344   32.932    0.001   93.520    0.002 {thrift.protocol.fastbinary.decode_binary}
    49344    0.184    0.000    0.184    0.000 {thrift.protocol.fastbinary.encode_binary}
      154   37.048    0.241   37.048    0.241 {time.sleep}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.strftime}
      159    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}
```

Comment: Both the database cursor and the file object should be caching reads and writes.  Working in blocks may not help as much as you think.

Comment: @Kevin what would be a sample way to do that if I want to give it a try?

Comment: I would suggest benchmarking to see where exactly time is spent.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I know that maximum time is spent in writing into file

Comment: @JasonDonnald Is it file writing or formatting the list into a string, then chopping off `[]` and then prepending `\n` to it?

Comment: @JasonDonnald: Maxim means *profiling*, not benchmarking.  See [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html).

Comment: I would suggest trying `csv.writer.writerow`.

Comment: Or, one-liner `csv.writer(write_file).writerows(cur.fetchall())`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: OP has too much data for `fetchall()`.

Comment: @Kevin May be `fetchall` returns a generator. If not, then do not do `fetchall`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin how can we do profiling to see timing for the way you have mentioned?

Comment: I suspect that this is the string formatting what may be slow.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: Just iterate over the cursor itself.  You don't need to play compatibility games with `fetchall()`.

Comment: `python -m cProfile [-o output_file] [-s sort_order] myscript.py`. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html?highlight=cprofile

Comment: @Kevin can you provide a sample for how to iterate over cursor?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin from the output of the profiling how can I tell which part is taking maximum time? Sorry for a naive question but I am new to this

Comment: I suggest reading that page.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin when I executed `python -m cProfile -o output_file.txt myscript.py` I get bunch of grabage characters in `output_file.txt`

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I have posted the profiling result in my post above

Comment: @Kevin I have posted the profiling result in above post

Comment: Now that you are looking at the profiler results, what are your thoughts?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I uanble to understand the output completely but I think some of the time is being spent in list formatting (`method 'append' of 'list' objects`) and some time is being spent in getting the data from the resultset

Answer (score 1):

If you save the output of the profiler into a file (I saved into file `a`) and sort it by the 2nd column `tottime` (the time spend in the function itself *excluding* called functions) and take the top 10 (not sure if giving it a `head` would be appropriate):

```
[max@supernova:~/tmp] $ sort --key=2nr a | head 
    49186 1153.582    0.023 1584.908    0.032 hiveserver2.py:263(fetch_results)
        1  286.275  286.275 2121.074 2121.074 test.py:24(func1)
  2245378  185.259    0.000  185.259    0.000 {method 'recv' of '_socket.socket' objects}
1107483909  105.411    0.000  105.411    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
1057142741   84.179    0.000   84.179    0.000 {ord}
 50340127   52.496    0.000 1693.039    0.000 hiveserver2.py:250(next)
 50340127   50.937    0.000 1760.004    0.000 hiveserver2.py:207(fetchone)
      154   37.048    0.241   37.048    0.241 {time.sleep}
 50340130   34.491    0.000   34.491    0.000 {method 'write' of 'file' objects}
    49344   32.932    0.001   93.520    0.002 {thrift.protocol.fastbinary.decode_binary}
```

Interpretation:

- The bulk of the time is spent in 49186 calls into `hiveserver2.py:263(fetch_results)`. I am not familiar with that library, but would I check if the number of calls could be reduced. Often, there are function prologue and epilogue costs, request/response overhead and such, so by reducing the number of calls you could cut down some overheads. May be do bulk result row fetching (i.e. more than one row at a time).
- Not sure what `test.py:24(func1)` does but it is the 2nd hot spot in the profiler output although it is called only once. Does it do any kind of a loop?
- Next is `185.259` time units, they are spent in 2245378 calls to `{method 'recv' of '_socket.socket' objects}`. That number of `recv` calls seems excessive, probably because of using `fetchone`, because it looks like it sends a new request over the socket for each row.
- Next `{method 'append' of 'list' objects}`, not enough information where it is being called from.
- Same for `{ord}`.
- Next, the two entries `hiveserver2.py:250(next)` and `hiveserver2.py:207(fetchone)` account for the most of total time (the 4th column).

Considering the above interpretation, it looks like calling `fetchone` is quite sub-optimal.

Instead of calling `fetchone` I would try calling `fetchall` if the resultset is guaranteed to fit into available memory, otherwise `fetchmany`, in order to load the recordset from the database using as few requests/batches as possible.

Comment: `test.py:24(func1)` is the function in which this whole code is placed in the script. Also the problem is that I am using `impala.dbapi` to connect to `impala` and this library does not provide `fetchmany`. It only provides either `fetchone` or `fetchall`.